# Making a "larger than" function with only basic arithmetic

Tags: functions, logic, arithmetic

Is it possible to make a function using only arithmetic (no logic operators), that can return 1 if it's input *x* is larger than a given number *a*, and 0 if it's less than *a*?

If it is, how would one construct it for any arbitrary value of *a*?

How could a "less than" function be constructed in a similar fashion?

Edit: If this is not possible, is it possible to construct a function that tends to 0 for all values of *x* below *a*, and tends to 1 for all values of *x* above *a*?

Comment: Are we talking about a function on natural numbers, integers or reals? When you say "only arithmetic", do you mean we are only supposed to use "normal operations" like $+,-,\cdot$ and $ /$ or are we allowed to use the whole scope of peano arithmetic? (i.e. recursion)

Comment: This is for real numbers, or at least positive real numbers (but i suspect that doesn't make a difference, since it can always be offset)

Comment: And also, only normal operations are allowed, no recursion :(

Comment: For integers, such a function is called [Digital Comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_comparator). It is composed of bitwise operations which in turn can be computed via arithmetic. Real numbers are more complicated to compare. This depends on the number representation.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for $a>0, x > 0$. Note this solution uses the floor operator ($\lfloor \rfloor$), which rounds a number down to the nearest integer, and the ceiling operator ($\lceil \rceil$), which rounds a number up to the nearest integer. Note this function returns $1$ if $x \le a$ and $0$ otherwise. $$f(x,a)=\left \lceil\left( \left\lfloor\frac{x}{a} \right\rfloor \right)\frac{1}{x}\right \rceil $$

Comment: This is a good solution, but unfortunately floor and ceil is not part of the normal +, −, ⋅  and / operations.